# comparar horarios

Tags: mysql

Algun me podria ayudar con un tema de SQL?
necesito saber cuales de los horarios registrados estan en horario lo cual realice asi

```
SELECT COUNT(id_horario) as col from horario WHERE horario >= now() AND status = 1;
```

ahora necesito seleccionar  las loterias que se encuentran en cada uno de los horarios, a lo que me refiero es que necesito saber cuales son

```
SELECT l.id_loteria,l.nombre,l.abreviatura,l.id_horario,h.horario FROM loteria as l INNER JOIN horario as h ON l.id_horario = h.id_horario  AND h.horario >= now() AND h.horario <= '15:30' WHERE l.status =1;
```

lo cual realice asi, pero esto es con un horario estatico y necesito que sea dinamico... en el sentido....
alguno me podria dar una idea?

Comment: dinamico, tomando el dato de donde?

Comment: por que no intentas donde esta la hora estatica colocar MAX(h.horario) para que traiga la hora maxima de lo que tienes registrado

Comment: Dinamico ya que se pueden cambiar los horarias o agregar mas horarios...

Comment: es que en cada horario hay diferentes loterias registradas y para cada horario debo crear una lista de check distinta